# How draw 2 things next each other?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How I can draw 2 cubes next each other? I mean two cubes like this but next to each other:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \foreach \n/\x/\l/\p in{
            1/{(0, 4)}/{$1$}/left,
            2/{(4, 4)}/{$2$}/south west,
            3/{(0, 0)}/{$3$}/below,
            4/{(4, 0)}/{$4$}/below,
            5/{(0.8, 4.8)}/{$5$}/above,
            6/{(4.8, 4.8)}/{$6$}/above,
            7/{(.8, 1)}/{$7$}/south east,
            8/{(4.8, 1)}/{$8$}/right
        }{
            \node[inner sep=2pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] (\n) at \x {};
        }
        \draw (1) -- (2) -- (4) -- (3) -- cycle;
        \draw (1) -- (2) -- (6) -- (5) -- cycle;
        \draw (2) -- (4) -- (8) -- (6) -- cycle;
        \draw (3) -- (1) -- (5);
        \draw[dashed] (5) -- (7) -- (3);
        \draw[dashed] (7) -- (8);
        
        \draw[pattern=north west lines] ($(1)!0.5!(3)$) -- ($(5)!0.5!(7)$) -- ($(6)!0.5!(8)$) -- ($(2)!0.5!(4)$) -- cycle;
        
        \node (a1) at ($(3)!0.5!(4) - (0,0.5)$) {$1\rightarrow3$};
        \node (a2) at ($(a1) - (0,0.5)$) {$5\rightarrow7$};
        \node (a3) at ($(a2) - (0,0.5)$) {$6\rightarrow8$};
        \node (a4) at ($(a3) - (0,0.5)$) {$2\rightarrow4$};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A "brute force" method would be to repeat all the code, inside the same `tikzpicture`, but increase all x-coordinates. That's rather inconvenient though, it's easier to use

```
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
<code for cube>
\end{scope}
```

A third option might be to use two `tikzpicture` environment, one immediately after the other. Below I used the `scope` approach.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \foreach \n/\x/\l/\p in{
            1/{(0, 4)}/{$1$}/left,
            2/{(4, 4)}/{$2$}/south west,
            3/{(0, 0)}/{$3$}/below,
            4/{(4, 0)}/{$4$}/below,
            5/{(0.8, 4.8)}/{$5$}/above,
            6/{(4.8, 4.8)}/{$6$}/above,
            7/{(.8, 1)}/{$7$}/south east,
            8/{(4.8, 1)}/{$8$}/right
        }{
            \node[inner sep=2pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] (\n) at \x {};
        }
        \draw (1) -- (2) -- (4) -- (3) -- cycle;
        \draw (1) -- (2) -- (6) -- (5) -- cycle;
        \draw (2) -- (4) -- (8) -- (6) -- cycle;
        \draw (3) -- (1) -- (5);
        \draw[dashed] (5) -- (7) -- (3);
        \draw[dashed] (7) -- (8);
        
        \draw[pattern=north west lines] ($(1)!0.5!(3)$) -- ($(5)!0.5!(7)$) -- ($(6)!0.5!(8)$) -- ($(2)!0.5!(4)$) -- cycle;
        
        \node (a1) at ($(3)!0.5!(4) - (0,0.5)$) {$1\rightarrow3$};
        \node (a2) at ($(a1) - (0,0.5)$) {$5\rightarrow7$};
        \node (a3) at ($(a2) - (0,0.5)$) {$6\rightarrow8$};
        \node (a4) at ($(a3) - (0,0.5)$) {$2\rightarrow4$};
        
    
    \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
        
        \foreach \n/\x/\l/\p in{
            1/{(0, 4)}/{$1$}/left,
            2/{(4, 4)}/{$2$}/south west,
            3/{(0, 0)}/{$3$}/below,
            4/{(4, 0)}/{$4$}/below,
            5/{(0.8, 4.8)}/{$5$}/above,
            6/{(4.8, 4.8)}/{$6$}/above,
            7/{(.8, 1)}/{$7$}/south east,
            8/{(4.8, 1)}/{$8$}/right
        }{
            \node[inner sep=2pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] (\n) at \x {};
        }
        \draw (1) -- (2) -- (4) -- (3) -- cycle;
        \draw (1) -- (2) -- (6) -- (5) -- cycle;
        \draw (2) -- (4) -- (8) -- (6) -- cycle;
        \draw (3) -- (1) -- (5);
        \draw[dashed] (5) -- (7) -- (3);
        \draw[dashed] (7) -- (8);
        
        \draw[pattern=north west lines] ($(1)!0.5!(3)$) -- ($(5)!0.5!(7)$) -- ($(6)!0.5!(8)$) -- ($(2)!0.5!(4)$) -- cycle;
        
        \node (a1) at ($(3)!0.5!(4) - (0,0.5)$) {$1\rightarrow3$};
        \node (a2) at ($(a1) - (0,0.5)$) {$5\rightarrow7$};
        \node (a3) at ($(a2) - (0,0.5)$) {$6\rightarrow8$};
        \node (a4) at ($(a3) - (0,0.5)$) {$2\rightarrow4$};
    
    \end{scope}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: if I have a third cube can I use scope again?

Comment: @sherek_66 Yes, of course.

Comment: it does not work with 3 cubes, the last cube doesn't show up

Comment: @sherek_66 I'd guess you've shifted it out of page, you might have to scale things down to make it fit (try `scale=0.6`in the tilzpicture options). That is just a guess though, if you can't make it work ask a new question and show what you did.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - On second thought, you can't shift out of t standalone page.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Indeed, that is true, didn't think of that.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use saveboxes or pics.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    
\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

 \savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \foreach \n/\x/\l/\p in{
            1/{(0, 4)}/{$1$}/left,
            2/{(4, 4)}/{$2$}/south west,
            3/{(0, 0)}/{$3$}/below,
            4/{(4, 0)}/{$4$}/below,
            5/{(0.8, 4.8)}/{$5$}/above,
            6/{(4.8, 4.8)}/{$6$}/above,
            7/{(.8, 1)}/{$7$}/south east,
            8/{(4.8, 1)}/{$8$}/right
        }{
            \node[inner sep=2pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] (\n) at \x {};
        }
        \draw (1) -- (2) -- (4) -- (3) -- cycle;
        \draw (1) -- (2) -- (6) -- (5) -- cycle;
        \draw (2) -- (4) -- (8) -- (6) -- cycle;
        \draw (3) -- (1) -- (5);
        \draw[dashed] (5) -- (7) -- (3);
        \draw[dashed] (7) -- (8);
        
        \draw[pattern=north west lines] ($(1)!0.5!(3)$) -- ($(5)!0.5!(7)$) -- ($(6)!0.5!(8)$) -- ($(2)!0.5!(4)$) -- cycle;
        
        \node (a1) at ($(3)!0.5!(4) - (0,0.5)$) {$1\rightarrow3$};
        \node (a2) at ($(a1) - (0,0.5)$) {$5\rightarrow7$};
        \node (a3) at ($(a2) - (0,0.5)$) {$6\rightarrow8$};
        \node (a4) at ($(a3) - (0,0.5)$) {$2\rightarrow4$};
    
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\usebox{\tempbox}\quad\usebox{\tempbox}\quad\usebox{\tempbox}
    
\end{document}
```